# how do i add images directly into firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am totally new to firebase and wanted to know what would be the best way store images in database.
There is about 50-100 images that I want to add and it comes around 300-400 mb.

I do know about firebase realtimeDatabase is there anyway i can store images in it ,if not what are some other viable options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to store images in a database is not at all.  Databases are typically not well suited for large amounts of binary data.  Consider [Cloud Storage for Firebase instead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Comment: So I should store images in cloud and give there path in database??

Comment: That's one way to do it.

Comment: will firebase realtimeDB do the job or should I opt for  firestore?

Comment: That's something you'll have to decide on your own, based on what your app needs and what you're comfortable with.  Stack Overflow isn't a place to get product recommendations.